# Responsive Table Fixed First Column Collapsed Columns into Rows

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have a table with the following layout:

```
---------------------
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
---------------------
| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 |
---------------------
```

When the user resizes the browser, I want to pivot the right columns in the table into the second column and have them behave as rows.  Instead of them stacking, I want them to pivot.  I have found numerous examples of the stacking online and it really isn't what I want.

Here is my desired output:

```
---------------------
| A1 | A2: B2       |
| B1 | A3: B3       |
|    | A4: B4       |
---------------------
```

Is this possible with media queries and CSS or do I need to start writing JavaScript?

Edit:

I didn't described the problem clearly enough: the table isn't just two rows, the table has multiple rows, with the A row being the Headers, for example:

```
---------------------
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
---------------------
| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 |
---------------------
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
---------------------
| D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
---------------------
```

to

```
---------------------
| A1 | A2: B2       |
| B1 | A3: B3       |
|    | A4: B4       |
---------------------
| A1 | A2: C2       |
| C1 | A3: C3       |
|    | A4: C4       |
---------------------
| A1 | A2: D2       |
| D1 | A3: D3       |
|    | A4: D4       |
---------------------
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at flexbox options and nesting the cells accordingly?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @SebCooper thanks, that looks like a really good option, I'm really tired fighting with tables, or making everything "act" like tables and then fighting with css

Comment: Yes tables are best suited to tabular data but can be inflexible with responsive presentation. It might be worth looking at using `display: table` related CSS too. Were you using tables to give you layout or for semantic reasons?
https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working jsfiddle demonstrating a basic flexbox implementation that solves for your layout issue:
[Nested Flexbox column-row switch demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3hnpa9x4/9/)

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table, .column, .column2 {
  display: flex; 
}
.column, .column2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column .cell-l1 {
  padding: 10px;
}
.cell-l1 {
  border: 1px solid teal;
   box-sizing: border-box; /* aesthetic rule not necessary for solution*/
   background: white; 
   flex-grow: 1;
}
.column2 .cell-l1 { 
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}
.cell-l2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cell-l2:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #DDD; /* alternating background color */
}

@media (max-width:768px){
  .column2 .cell-l1 { 
    flex-direction: column;    
   }
   .column2 {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell-l1">
      A1
    </div>
    <div class="cell-l1">
      B1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="cell-l1">
      <div class="cell-l2">
        A2
      </div>
      <div class="cell-l2">
        A3
      </div>
      <div class="cell-l2">
        A4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-l1">
      <div class="cell-l2">
        B2
      </div>
      <div class="cell-l2">
        B3
      </div>
      <div class="cell-l2">
        B4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```